# If $Y| \mu \sim N(\mu, A)$ and $\mu \sim N(\mu_0, B)$, showing the marginal of $Y$ is $Y \sim N(\mu_0, A+B)$

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

I have an n-dimensional multivariate distribution:

$$
Y| \mu \sim N(\mu, A)
$$

and a prior of:

$$
\mu \sim N(\mu_0, B)
$$

I would like to show that the marginal distribution of $Y$ is:

$$
Y \sim N(\mu_0, A+B)
$$

My approach is to recognize:

$$
p(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(Y|\mu) p(\mu) d\mu
$$

This ultimately yields:

$$
p(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2^{-\frac{k}{2}}|A|^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^{T}A^{-1}(y-\mu)} 2^{-\frac{k}{2}}|B|^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\mu-\mu_0)^{T}B^{-1}(\mu-\mu_0)} d\mu
$$

To solve this is a mess and I am stuck here. Is there a simpler way to find the marginal? Thanks.

Comment: The basics of the usual tactic (completing the square) is covered in a number of questions on site: Pull out the constants (things not in $\mu$). Combine the exponents. Expand as quadratic form in $\mu$ and complete the square. Pull out another constant. Recognize the density. Supply any missing parts of the normalizing constant and divide by the same. Integral of a density is 1 so cross it out. Simplify the remaining function of y.

Comment: e.g. what you have is a slightly simpler version of [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139522/completing-the-square-for-gaussian-multivariate-estimation) and [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33418/how-do-i-complete-the-square-with-normal-likelihood-and-normal-prior)